# Schedule background task in android and call react-native javascript method from task

Tags: react-native

I need to be able to schedule a background job for andorid and call react-native javascript method from the background job whenever the job triggers. Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

React Native introduced [Headless JS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/headless-js-android.html) for Android. With that you can start a custom `HeadlessJsTaskService` that will run your JavaScript code.